# How do I change the shortcut-key of show the unity dash?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

I don't want to use the <kbd>Super</kbd> for that, I want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 7):

Open the Terminal and execute the following command:

```bsh
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher '"<Alt>space"'
```

To read the current value, use `read` option:

```
dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher
```

If you want to set it to default value, use `reset` option as following:

```
dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher
```

---

From [man dconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dconf.1.html):

```
dconf read KEY
dconf write KEY VALUE
dconf reset [-f] PATH
```

- read : Read the value of a key.
- write: Write a new value to a key.
- reset: Reset a key or an entire directory. For directories, `-f` must be specified.

Comment: Wow this is awesome! How did you learn about that key, since it doesn't exist by default?

Comment: @Seth I used CCSM's GUI method to changing that and monitored its change by `dconf watch /`, and I get that above schema-path getting change. So I used `dconf read/write ... ` to change it without GUI :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) to set which shortcut opens the dash or to disable it.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then from the terminal start it by executing ccsm, find the Ubuntu Unity Plugin and select the Launcher tab. Disable the "Key to show Dash..." shortcut.