# How can I disable the Mac Command key triggering the big HUD coming up in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, apple, hud

This applies to Ubuntu 14.04 running in a VMWare environment on a OS X host.

Everytime I press the apple command key to e.g. command-tab to another (OS X) application, the HUD comes up in Ubuntu. Not the regular (small search box) HUD, but the big mondo one that looks a bit like the Apple launchpad, and is about equally useless.

I've tried disabling/changing the key binding in the system settings to use e.g. the backslash key. That works fine, on backslash, the HUD comes up. But on apple command key press, that big mondo special search HUD still comes up, no matter what I do.

Any help anyone?

Comment: Are you referring to [the dash](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=985&q=unity+dash&oq=unity+dash&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i30j0i8i30j0i24l6.603.1422.0.1561.10.7.0.0.0.0.159.545.4j2.6.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.img..4.6.544.aMPrfu4BkM8)?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/576019/how-do-i-change-the-shortcut-key-of-show-the-unity-dash?noredirect=1) then!

Comment: it helps to know that this is called the dash... I didn't know that, so thanks for pointing that out. I used ccsm to disable the shortcut.

Comment: You might consider adding that as an answer to the other question with screenshots and steps :)

Comment: I can't because you marked it as a duplicate... :-)

Comment: I meant the question I marked it as a duplicate of ;)