# Restore super key to open dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I just got my new laptop with Ubuntu preinstalled, and the super key doesn't open the dash. I have installed `compizconfig-settings-manager`, where I can assign a key combination like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, but it won't let me assign the <kbd>Super</kbd> key by itself.

How can I make the super key work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576019/how-do-i-change-the-shortcut-key-of-show-the-unity-dash) that provided a command-line solution for changing the launcher key shortcut. Restoring the default behavior only takes a single command:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher '"<Super>"'
```